# Multiple-criteria decision analysis of MVC vs Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, model-view-controller, comparison, flux

I would like to create a more scientific-related comparison of MVC vs Flux for React apps.

The thing is I don't know how to make it unbiased, eg. sayings like "Flux is better because there is 20 posts saying that it's better suited for React apps so it must be better"...
I need to avoid such amateur comparison and focus on core  problems of both patterns.

But which aspects should I compare?
How can I quantify/qualify such comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way with Focus Groups method that will spit criterias. These criterias can be applied with Saat's method to determine what's better for what.